# UNALIGNED Usage Fault on LDR instruction-CortexM7

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded, cortex-m, thumb

I am debugging an assembly code written for a CortexM7 target. Inside the busFault handler there is a LDR instruction which when executed causes a UNALIGNED Usage Fault and as a result a forced Hard Fault occurs. What I know is that by default there is no address alignment requirement for ldr instruction. 
I have also checked the the bit in CCR register which can enforce the requirement but it is disabled. 
Following is my code:

```
global          c_AbcFunction

c_Abc        .long c_AbcFunction    

BusFaultHandler:
LDR R1, c_Abc
```

Compiler: ARM-GHS 2017
Debugger: Lauterbach

Value of CCR:

```
 CCR  00040200  BP           Enabled            IC            Disabled   DC             Disabled
                STKALIGN     8-byte/adjustment  BFHFNMIGN     Lockup     DIV_0_TRP      Disabled
                UNALIGN_TRP  Disabled           USERSETMPEND  Disabled   NONBASETHRDENA Disabled
```

Disassembly of above code:

```
0128      c_Abc:        align   0x128
2802                                       ////////                 ; instruction would span across HLL line symbol

BusFaultHandler:
    LDR R1, c_Abc
F85F102E   ldr     r1,0x10013318
```

The change I made in for strict Alignment:

```
c_Abc  .long   c_AbcFunction
.align    4
```

Disassembly after adding ".align 4":

```
28020128  c_Abc:        stmdacs r2,{r3,r5,r8}

BusFaultHandler:
    LDR R1, c_Abc
F85F1030                                   ldr     r1,0x10013318    ; r1,c_Abc
```

The underlying issue is somehow fixed by adding .align 4. But I cannot understand the reason as LDR should not have any alignment requirement in the current scenario.

Comment: Is your `c_Abc` actually aligned?  Use `.p2align 2` before it to insert padding to reach a `2^2 = 4` boundary, or whatever other directive your assembler uses.

Comment: show the disassembly please

Comment: please show the CCR register value as well.

Comment: @old_timer Value of CCR is 00040200 and the UNALIGN_TRP flag is disabled.

Comment: and the value at 0x10013318?

Comment: Can value saved at this address cause problem?

Comment: just reading the dissassembly and seeing what is missing from it...

Comment: why does the disassembler(?) show 28020128 for the label as well as 0x1001331, either way is the value being used as an address shown in this output?  not familiar with this tools output.

Answer (score 1):

The alignment fault may have nothing to do with the `LDR` instruction. A misaligned Vector Table seems a more likely culprit. Check to see if the table is on at least a 128 byte boundary. If not, the vector fetch may be the actual source of the fault.

Also, your listing shows `align 0x128`, but that directive typically requires a power-of-two. Should it be `align 128` instead?

Comment: The value of VTOR is 0x28000000 fulfils the alignment requirements.

Comment: align 0x128 is a compiler generated instruction against my variable definition. But when I add align 4 new instruction generated as shown by debugger is stmdacs r2,{r3,r5,r8}.

Comment: @SS01 Have you examined the vector table to ensure correct initialization (i.e. correct address of BusFaultHandler with the least-significant bit set)? It still seems to me that the alignment fault is more likely occurring prior to the `LDR` instruction.

Comment: align is not an instruction.  and how align works is dependent on the assembler as it is assembly language and assembler and in some cases like gas target specific.